# Window air conditioner exhaust temperature

Tags: hvac

I'm planning to put a window air conditioner in an apartment awning window. The window part that swings open cannot be removed so,the exhaust from the air conditioner would be blowing against the window. Would the exhaust be very hot and,if so could it cause damage to the window parts? Any suggestions?

Comment: the thermal cutout of the AC will trigger before the window will melt.

Comment: If you are  restricting the air flow from the rear of the A/C unit then you can't install a window A/C in that window. You need to find another solution.